# What are the various join types in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I looked at the docs and it says the following join types are supported:

> Type of join to perform. Default inner. Must be one of: inner, cross,
>   outer, full, full_outer, left, left_outer, right, right_outer,
>   left_semi, left_anti.

I looked at the [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins) on SQL joins and top couple of answers do not mention some of the joins from above e.g. `left_semi` and `left_anti`. What do they mean in Spark?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Here is a simple illustrative experiment:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._

object SparkSandbox extends App {
  implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  val left = Seq((1, "A1"), (2, "A2"), (3, "A3"), (4, "A4")).toDF("id", "value")
  val right = Seq((3, "A3"), (4, "A4"), (4, "A4_1"), (5, "A5"), (6, "A6")).toDF("id", "value")

  println("LEFT")
  left.orderBy("id").show()

  println("RIGHT")
  right.orderBy("id").show()

  val joinTypes = Seq("inner", "outer", "full", "full_outer", "left", "left_outer", "right", "right_outer", "left_semi", "left_anti")

  joinTypes foreach { joinType =>
    println(s"${joinType.toUpperCase()} JOIN")
    left.join(right = right, usingColumns = Seq("id"), joinType = joinType).orderBy("id").show()
  }
}
```

Output

```
LEFT
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|   A1|
|  2|   A2|
|  3|   A3|
|  4|   A4|
+---+-----+

RIGHT
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  3|   A3|
|  4|   A4|
|  4| A4_1|
|  5|   A5|
|  6|   A6|
+---+-----+

INNER JOIN
+---+-----+-----+
| id|value|value|
+---+-----+-----+
|  3|   A3|   A3|
|  4|   A4| A4_1|
|  4|   A4|   A4|
+---+-----+-----+

OUTER JOIN
+---+-----+-----+
| id|value|value|
+---+-----+-----+
|  1|   A1| null|
|  2|   A2| null|
|  3|   A3|   A3|
|  4|   A4|   A4|
|  4|   A4| A4_1|
|  5| null|   A5|
|  6| null|   A6|
+---+-----+-----+

FULL JOIN
+---+-----+-----+
| id|value|value|
+---+-----+-----+
|  1|   A1| null|
|  2|   A2| null|
|  3|   A3|   A3|
|  4|   A4|   A4|
|  4|   A4| A4_1|
|  5| null|   A5|
|  6| null|   A6|
+---+-----+-----+

FULL_OUTER JOIN
+---+-----+-----+
| id|value|value|
+---+-----+-----+
|  1|   A1| null|
|  2|   A2| null|
|  3|   A3|   A3|
|  4|   A4|   A4|
|  4|   A4| A4_1|
|  5| null|   A5|
|  6| null|   A6|
+---+-----+-----+

LEFT JOIN
+---+-----+-----+
| id|value|value|
+---+-----+-----+
|  1|   A1| null|
|  2|   A2| null|
|  3|   A3|   A3|
|  4|   A4| A4_1|
|  4|   A4|   A4|
+---+-----+-----+

LEFT_OUTER JOIN
+---+-----+-----+
| id|value|value|
+---+-----+-----+
|  1|   A1| null|
|  2|   A2| null|
|  3|   A3|   A3|
|  4|   A4| A4_1|
|  4|   A4|   A4|
+---+-----+-----+

RIGHT JOIN
+---+-----+-----+
| id|value|value|
+---+-----+-----+
|  3|   A3|   A3|
|  4|   A4| A4_1|
|  4|   A4|   A4|
|  5| null|   A5|
|  6| null|   A6|
+---+-----+-----+

RIGHT_OUTER JOIN
+---+-----+-----+
| id|value|value|
+---+-----+-----+
|  3|   A3|   A3|
|  4|   A4|   A4|
|  4|   A4| A4_1|
|  5| null|   A5|
|  6| null|   A6|
+---+-----+-----+

LEFT_SEMI JOIN
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  3|   A3|
|  4|   A4|
+---+-----+

LEFT_ANTI JOIN
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|   A1|
|  2|   A2|
+---+-----+
```

Comment: Please update the answer with cross join. See https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/joinTypes.scala

Comment: Why no difference between full and full outer join ?

Comment: @sapy Because `"outer"`, `"full"`, and `"fullouter"` just different aliases for the exact same join type. See code: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1b9fd67904671ea08526bfb7a97d694815d47665/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/joinTypes.scala#L27

Answer (score 8):

Loved Pathikrit's example. Here is a possible translation in Java using Spark v2 and dataframes, including cross-join.

```
package net.jgp.books.sparkInAction.ch12.lab940AllJoins;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

/**
 * All joins in a single app, inspired by
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990633/what-are-the-various-join-types-in-spark.
 * 
 * Used in Spark in Action 2e, http://jgp.net/sia
 * 
 * @author jgp
 */
public class AllJoinsApp {

  /**
   * main() is your entry point to the application.
   * 
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AllJoinsApp app = new AllJoinsApp();
    app.start();
  }

  /**
   * The processing code.
   */
  private void start() {
    // Creates a session on a local master
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("Processing of invoices")
        .master("local")
        .getOrCreate();

    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
        DataTypes.createStructField(
            "id",
            DataTypes.IntegerType,
            false),
        DataTypes.createStructField(
            "value",
            DataTypes.StringType,
            false) });

    List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
    rows.add(RowFactory.create(1, "A1"));
    rows.add(RowFactory.create(2, "A2"));
    rows.add(RowFactory.create(3, "A3"));
    rows.add(RowFactory.create(4, "A4"));
    Dataset<Row> dfLeft = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema);
    dfLeft.show();

    rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
    rows.add(RowFactory.create(3, "A3"));
    rows.add(RowFactory.create(4, "A4"));
    rows.add(RowFactory.create(4, "A4_1"));
    rows.add(RowFactory.create(5, "A5"));
    rows.add(RowFactory.create(6, "A6"));
    Dataset<Row> dfRight = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema);
    dfRight.show();

    String[] joinTypes = new String[] { 
        "inner", // v2.0.0. default
        "cross", // v2.2.0
        "outer", // v2.0.0
        "full", // v2.1.1
        "full_outer", // v2.1.1
        "left", // v2.1.1
        "left_outer", // v2.0.0
        "right", // v2.1.1
        "right_outer", // v2.0.0
        "left_semi", // v2.0.0, was leftsemi before v2.1.1
        "left_anti" // v2.1.1
        };

    for (String joinType : joinTypes) {
      System.out.println(joinType.toUpperCase() + " JOIN");
      Dataset<Row> df = dfLeft.join(
          dfRight, 
          dfLeft.col("id").equalTo(dfRight.col("id")), 
          joinType);
      df.orderBy(dfLeft.col("id")).show();
    }
  }
}
```

I'll put this example in the [Spark in Action, 2e](http://jgp.net/sia)'s [chapter 12 repository](https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.books.sparkWithJava.ch12).

Answer (score 2):

```
Spark data frame support following types of joins between two dataframes.
Please find the list of joins and joining string with respect to join types along with scala syntax.
We can use following joining values used for specify the join type in Scala- Spark code. 
***Mathod:*** Leftdataframe.join(Rightdataframe, join_conditions, joinStringName)

Join Name : Join String name in scala -Spark code

1. inner : 'inner'
2. cross: 'cross'
3. outer: 'outer'
4. full: 'full'
5. full outer: 'fullouter'
6. left : 'left'
7. left outer : 'leftouter'
8. right : 'right'
9. right outer : 'rightouter'
10. left semi: 'leftsemi'
11. left anti: 'leftanti'

example: 1. Left Semi join: 
Leftdataframe.join(Rightdataframe, join_conditions, "leftsemi");
2. inner Join Example:
Leftdataframe.join(Rightdataframe, join_conditions, "inner");

Its tested and working well.
```

Answer (score 1):

Left Semi returns rows where the join key is found in both tables, but it only includes the fields from the left table.

Left Anti returns rows where the join key is found only in the left table.

Good descriptions of the different join types:
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_joins.html

Answer (score 0):

***Supported join types include:***

```
   inner  
    outer  
     full  
      fullouter  
       full_outer  
        leftouter  
         left  
          left_outer  
           rightouter  
            right  
             right_outer  
              leftsemi  
               left_semi  
                leftanti  
                 left_anti  
                  cross
```