# Scala - Merge Two RDDs Based on Key in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm writing a Spark application using Scala. I have the following two RDDs:

```
(a, 1, some_values1)
(b, 1, some_values2)
(c, 1, some_values3)
```

and

```
(a, 2, some_values1)
(b, 2, some_values2)
(a, 3, some_values1)
(b, 3, some_values2)
```

I'm trying to get this output:

```
(a, 1, 2, computed_values1)
(b, 1, 2, computed_values2)
(c, 1, 2, None)
(a, 1, 3, computed_values1)
(b, 1, 3, computed_values2)
(c, 1, 3, None)
```

So, the letters here are used to match each record from the first RDD with the second one. I tried using the `join` method but didn't work for record `c`. How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

Another example:

```
(a, 1, some_values1)
(b, 1, some_values2)
(c, 1, some_values3)
```

and

```
(a, 2, some_values1)
(b, 2, some_values2)
(a, 3, some_values1)
(b, 3, some_values2)
(c, 3, some_values2)
```

I'm trying to get this output:

```
(a, 1, 2, computed_values1)
(b, 1, 2, computed_values2)
(c, 1, 2, None)
(a, 1, 3, computed_values1)
(b, 1, 3, computed_values2)
(c, 1, 3, computed_values3)
```

Comment: Join "outer" can be used for preserve row from both dataframes, some info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990633/what-are-the-various-join-types-in-spark

Comment: @pasha701 Yeah I know, actually I tried using the outer join to achieve that but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, here's an approach:

1. Create a RDD, say `rdd2c2`, of distinct values from the 2nd column of `rdd2`
2. Perform a `cartesian join` on `rdd1` and `rdd2c2` and transform the result to a RDD[K,V] to make `the` 1st column and the `rdd2c2` column as its `key`
3. Transfrom `rdd2` to a RDD[K,V] to make its 1st and 2nd columns as its `key`
4. Perform a `leftOuterJoin` on the two RDD[K,V]s and transform elements to desired structure

Sample code:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("a", 1, "some_values1"),
  ("b", 1, "some_values2"),
  ("c", 1, "some_values3")
))

val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("a", 2, "some_values1"),
  ("b", 2, "some_values2"),
  ("a", 3, "some_values1"),
  ("b", 3, "some_values2"),
  ("c", 3, "some_values2")
))

val rdd2c2 = rdd2.map(_._2).distinct
// rdd2c2.collect: Array[Int] = Array(2, 3)

val rddKV1 = rdd1.cartesian(rdd2c2).
  map{ case (a, b) => ((a._1, b), (a._2, a._3))}
// rddKV1.collect: Array[((String, Int), (Int, String))] = Array(
//   ((a,2),(1,some_values1)),
//   ((a,3),(1,some_values1)),
//   ((b,2),(1,some_values2)),
//   ((b,3),(1,some_values2)),
//   ((c,2),(1,some_values3)),
//   ((c,3),(1,some_values3)))

val rddKV2 = rdd2.map(r => ((r._1, r._2), r._3))
// rddKV2.collect: Array[((String, Int), String)] = Array(
//   ((a,2),some_values1),
//   ((b,2),some_values2),
//   ((a,3),some_values1),
//   ((b,3),some_values2),
//   ((c,3),some_values2))

val rddJoined = rddKV1.leftOuterJoin(rddKV2).
  map{ case (k, v) => (k._1, v._1._1, k._2, v._2) }
// rddJoined.collect: Array[(String, Int, Int, Option[String])] = Array(
//   (a,1,3,Some(some_values1)),
//   (a,1,2,Some(some_values1)),
//   (c,1,2,None),
//   (b,1,2,Some(some_values2)),
//   (b,1,3,Some(some_values2)),
//   (c,1,3,Some(some_values2)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This will actually produce the expected result for the given example. But the issue here is that if rdd2 has let's say "c" with "3", the resulting rdd will not include this: (c, 1, 2, None). I'll update my question to add this example as well.

Comment: @m2008m1033m, please see revised solution based on my understanding of your clarified requirement.

Comment: It worked, thanks! Regarding the note at the end, if the distinct list is very large (because it actually is), can we use the sc.broadcast with it?

Comment: In fact, using a suitably crafted `cartesian join` would remove the need of `collect`.  Solution further revised.

Answer (score 0):

If "c" have to be in result only once (guess, misprint in desired output), can be achived with such code:

```
val data1 = List(
  ("a", 1, "some_values1"),
  ("b", 1, "some_values2"),
  ("c", 1, "some_values3")
)

val data2 = List(
  ("a", 2, "some_values1"),
  ("b", 2, "some_values2"),
  ("a", 3, "some_values1"),
  ("b", 3, "some_values2")
)

val rdd1 = sparkContext.parallelize(data1)
val rdd2 = sparkContext.parallelize(data2)

val rdd1WithKey = rdd1.map(v => (v._1, (v._2, v._3)))
val rdd2WithKey = rdd2.map(v => (v._1, (v._2, v._3)))

val joined = rdd1WithKey.fullOuterJoin(rdd2WithKey)
joined.foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
(b,(Some((1,some_values2)),Some((2,some_values2))))
(a,(Some((1,some_values1)),Some((2,some_values1))))
(b,(Some((1,some_values2)),Some((3,some_values2))))
(a,(Some((1,some_values1)),Some((3,some_values1))))
(c,(Some((1,some_values3)),None))
```

Comment: That was the issue. I'm trying to get "c" for every number in the second rdd.