# How to join two DataFrame with combined columns in Spark?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I don't understand how I can join such 2 DataFrame with each other.

First DataFrame store information about request time of the user to service center.

Let's call this DataFrame `df1`:

```
+-----------+---------------------+
| USER_NAME | REQUEST_DATE        |
+-----------+---------------------+
| Alex      | 2018-03-01 00:00:00 |
| Alex      | 2018-09-01 00:00:00 |
| Bob       | 2018-03-01 00:00:00 |
| Mark      | 2018-02-01 00:00:00 |
| Mark      | 2018-07-01 00:00:00 |
| Kate      | 2018-02-01 00:00:00 |
+-----------+---------------------+
```

Second DataFrame store information about possible period when the user can use the services of the service center (license period).

Lets call it `df2`.

```
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
| USER_NAME | START_SERVICE       | END_SERVICE         | STATUS     |
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
| Alex      | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2018-06-01 00:00:00 | Active     |
| Bob       | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | Not Active |
| Mark      | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2018-05-01 23:59:59 | Active     |
| Mark      | 2018-05-01 00:00:00 | 2018-08-01 23:59:59 | VIP        |
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
```

How to join these 2 DataFrame and return such result? How to get list of users license type at the time of treatment?

```
+-----------+---------------------+----------------+
| USER_NAME | REQUEST_DATE        | STATUS         |
+-----------+---------------------+----------------+
| Alex      | 2018-03-01 00:00:00 | Active         |
| Alex      | 2018-09-01 00:00:00 | No information |
| Bob       | 2018-03-01 00:00:00 | Not Active     |
| Mark      | 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | Active         |
| Mark      | 2018-07-01 00:00:00 | VIP            |
| Kate      | 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | No information |
+-----------+---------------------+----------------+
```

**CODE:**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

val df1: DataFrame  = Seq(
    ("Alex", "2018-03-01 00:00:00"),
    ("Alex", "2018-09-01 00:00:00"),
    ("Bob", "2018-03-01 00:00:00"),
    ("Mark", "2018-02-01 00:00:00"),
    ("Mark", "2018-07-01 00:00:00"),
    ("Kate", "2018-07-01 00:00:00")
).toDF("USER_NAME", "REQUEST_DATE")

df1.show()

val df2: DataFrame  = Seq(
    ("Alex", "2018-01-01 00:00:00", "2018-06-01 00:00:00", "Active"),
    ("Bob", "2018-01-01 00:00:00", "2018-02-01 00:00:00", "Not Active"),
    ("Mark", "2018-01-01 00:00:00", "2018-05-01 23:59:59", "Active"),
    ("Mark", "2018-05-01 00:00:00", "2018-08-01 23:59:59", "Active")
).toDF("USER_NAME", "START_SERVICE", "END_SERVICE", "STATUS")

df1.show()

val total = df1.join(df2, df1("USER_NAME")===df2("USER_NAME"), "left").filter(df1("REQUEST_DATE") >= df2("START_SERVICE") && df1("REQUEST_DATE") <= df2("END_SERVICE")).select(df1("*"), df2("STATUS"))

total.show()
```

**ERROR**:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
  at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.doExecuteBroadcast(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:136)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doExecuteBroadcast(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:367)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:144)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeBroadcast(SparkPlan.scala:140)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.prepareBroadcast(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:135)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.codegenInner(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:232)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.doConsume(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:102)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:181)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.consume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doConsume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:181)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.consume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:85)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.doConsume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:206)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:181)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:354)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doProduce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:383)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:88)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:83)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:83)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:354)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.doProduce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:125)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:88)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:83)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:83)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.produce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:85)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doProduce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:45)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:88)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:83)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:83)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.produce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.doProduce(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:97)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:88)
```

Answer (score 2):

How to join these 2 DataFrame and return such result?

```
df_joined = df1.join(df2, Seq('USER_NAME'), 'left' )
```

How to get a list of all users whose licenses are still relevant?

```
df_relevant = df_joined
.withColumn('STATUS', when(col('REQUEST_DATE') > col('START_SERVICE') and col('REQUEST_DATE') < col('END_SERVICE'), col('STATUS')).otherwise('No information') 
.select('USER_NAME', 'REQUEST_DATE', 'STATUS' )
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. Can you check my post again please. I change DataFrame information. What can you advice in that case?

Comment: Hi, this answer is very good. Except that you don't specify the type of join you're using. By default, it is probably `left` or `inner`, I don't know and don't want to know, it's better to always specify it. I reckon it probably doesn't really matter here but as @NurzhanNogerbek seems new with joins, I think it would be good to point it. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990633/what-are-the-various-join-types-in-spark for more info about `join` in `spark`.

Comment: Guys can you check my post again please? I add code. It raise error when I try to join. Where I did mistake?

Comment: Thanks for comments, changed my answer according to new question. Can't run now, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing <= and >= on string values which is incorrect. You should cast them to timestamps before doing such comparisons. The below code worked for me.

BTW.. the filter condition that you used is not giving the results, that you posted in the question. Please check it again.

```
scala> val df= Seq(("Alex","2018-03-01 00:00:00"),("Alex","2018-09-01 00:00:00"),("Bob","2018-03-01 00:00:00"),("Mark","2018-02-01 00:00:00"),("Mark","2018-07-01 00:00:00"),("Kate","2018-02-01 00:00:00")).toDF("USER_NAME","REQUEST_DATE").withColumn("REQUEST_DATE",to_timestamp('REQUEST_DATE))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [USER_NAME: string, REQUEST_DATE: timestamp]

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- USER_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- REQUEST_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)


scala> df.show(false)
+---------+-------------------+
|USER_NAME|REQUEST_DATE       |
+---------+-------------------+
|Alex     |2018-03-01 00:00:00|
|Alex     |2018-09-01 00:00:00|
|Bob      |2018-03-01 00:00:00|
|Mark     |2018-02-01 00:00:00|
|Mark     |2018-07-01 00:00:00|
|Kate     |2018-02-01 00:00:00|
+---------+-------------------+


scala> val df2 = Seq(( "Alex","2018-01-01 00:00:00","2018-06-01 00:00:00","Active"),("Bob","2018-01-01 00:00:00","2018-02-01 00:00:00","Not Active"),("Mark","2018-01-01 00:00:00","2018-05-01 23:59:59","Active"),("Mark","2018-05-01 00:00:00","2018-08-01 23:59:59","VIP")).toDF("USER_NAME","START_SERVICE","END_SERVICE","STATUS").withColumn("START_SERVICE",to_timestamp('START_SERVICE)).withColumn("END_SERVICE",to_timestamp('END_SERVICE))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [USER_NAME: string, START_SERVICE: timestamp ... 2 more fields]

scala> df2.printSchema
root
 |-- USER_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- START_SERVICE: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- END_SERVICE: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- STATUS: string (nullable = true)


scala> df2.show(false)
+---------+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
|USER_NAME|START_SERVICE      |END_SERVICE        |STATUS    |
+---------+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
|Alex     |2018-01-01 00:00:00|2018-06-01 00:00:00|Active    |
|Bob      |2018-01-01 00:00:00|2018-02-01 00:00:00|Not Active|
|Mark     |2018-01-01 00:00:00|2018-05-01 23:59:59|Active    |
|Mark     |2018-05-01 00:00:00|2018-08-01 23:59:59|VIP       |
+---------+-------------------+-------------------+----------+


scala> df.join(df2,Seq("USER_NAME"),"leftOuter").filter(" REQUEST_DATE >= START_SERVICE and REQUEST_DATE <= END_SERVICE").select(df("*"),df2("status")).show(false)
+---------+-------------------+------+
|USER_NAME|REQUEST_DATE       |status|
+---------+-------------------+------+
|Alex     |2018-03-01 00:00:00|Active|
|Mark     |2018-02-01 00:00:00|Active|
|Mark     |2018-07-01 00:00:00|VIP   |
+---------+-------------------+------+


scala>
```