# Pyspark SQL query to get rows that are +/- 20% of a specific column

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following pyspark df:

```
+------------------+--------+-------+
|                ID|  Assets|Revenue|
+------------------+--------+-------+
|201542399349300619| 1633944|  32850|
|201542399349300629| 3979760| 850914|
|201542399349300634| 3402687|1983568|
|201542399349300724| 1138291|1097553|
|201522369349300122| 1401406|1010828|
|201522369349300137|   16948| 171534|
|201522369349300142|13474056|2285323|
|201522369349300202|  481045| 241788|
|201522369349300207|  700861|1185640|
|201522369349300227|  178479| 267976|
+------------------+--------+-------+
```

For each row, I want to be able to get the rows that are within 20% of the Assets amount. For example, for the first row (ID=201542399349300619), I want to be able to get all the rows where Assets are within 20% +/- of 1,633,944 (so between 1,307,155 to 1,960,732):

```
+------------------+--------+-------+
|                ID|  Assets|Revenue|
+------------------+--------+-------+
|201542399349300619| 1633944|  32850|
|201522369349300122| 1401406|1010828|
```

Using this subsetted table, I want to get the average assets and add it as a new column. So for the above example, it would be the average assets of (1633944+1401406) = 1517675

```
+------------------+--------+-------+---------+
|                ID|  Assets|Revenue|AvgAssets|
+------------------+--------+-------+---------+
|201542399349300619| 1633944|  32850|  1517675|
```

Comment: @pault My mistake, I have corrected the typos. I am not very familiar with SQL, hence I want to just get some guidance on how I can achieve this with what I have in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your DataFrame has a schema similar to the following (i.e. `Assets` and `Revenue` are numeric):

```python
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- ID: long (nullable = true)
# |-- Assets: integer (nullable = true)
# |-- Revenue: integer (nullable = true)
```

You can [join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins) the DataFrame to itself on the condition that you've set forth. After the join, you can group and aggregate by taking the average of the `Assets` column.

For example:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, expr

df.alias("l")\
    .join(
        df.alias("r"), 
        on=expr("r.assets between l.assets*0.8 and l.assets*1.2")
    )\
    .groupBy("l.ID", "l.Assets", "l.Revenue")\
    .agg(avg("r.Assets").alias("AvgAssets"))\
    .show()
#+------------------+--------+-------+------------------+
#|                ID|  Assets|Revenue|         AvgAssets|
#+------------------+--------+-------+------------------+
#|201542399349300629| 3979760| 850914|         3691223.5|
#|201522369349300202|  481045| 241788|          481045.0|
#|201522369349300207|  700861|1185640|          700861.0|
#|201522369349300137|   16948| 171534|           16948.0|
#|201522369349300142|13474056|2285323|       1.3474056E7|
#|201522369349300227|  178479| 267976|          178479.0|
#|201542399349300619| 1633944|  32850|         1517675.0|
#|201522369349300122| 1401406|1010828|1391213.6666666667|
#|201542399349300724| 1138291|1097553|         1138291.0|
#|201542399349300634| 3402687|1983568|         3691223.5|
#+------------------+--------+-------+------------------+
```

Since we are joining the DataFrame to itself, we can use aliases to refer to the left table (`"l"`) and the right table (`"r"`). The logic above says join `l` to `r` on the condition that the assets in `r` is +/20% of the assets in `l`.

There are multiple ways to express the +/20% condition, but I am using the spark-sql `between` expression to find rows that are between `Assets * 0.8` and `Assets * 1.2`.

Then we aggregate on all of the columns (`groupBy`) of the left table and average over the assets in the right table.

The resulting `AvgAssets` column is a `FloatType` column, but you can easily convert it to `IntegerType` by adding a `.cast("int")` before the `.alias("AvgAssets")` if that's what you prefer.

---

See also:

- [What are the various join types in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990633/what-are-the-various-join-types-in-spark)