# Spark inner join API returns too many records

Tags: apache-spark, inner-join

[File link here](https://filebin.net/bqdbgcuuc6jbnbpy/annual-enterprise-survey-2018-financial-year-provisional-csv.csv?t=9mkxw7wu) I have two same dataframes each has 27817 rows.Try to inner join these dataframes it returns 128954989 rows.

dataframe1.join(dataframe2,"_c0").count
res16: Long = 128954989

how to resolve this .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please go through [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: check same logic with less number records in dataframes with same schema. If it gives issue then post your question in proper details including both dataframes and join operation.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Also, links die. Insert images/links using edit functions. Make your post self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your join is creating cartesian products. If you want to keep the rows on the left side of the join you can do a left join like:

```
dataframe1.join(dataframe2,"_c0", "left")
```

Also you have more types of joins and you have to select one of them deppending on your necessity. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990633/what-are-the-various-join-types-in-spark) you can see the join trypes with examples: