# How can we compare two dataframes in spark scala to find difference between these 2 files, which column ?? and value?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I have two files and I created two dataframes prod1 and prod2 out of it.I need to find the records with column names and values that are not matching in both the dfs.
id_sk is the primary key .all the cols are string datatype

dataframe 1 (prod1)

```
id_sk | uuid|name
1     |10   |a
2     |20   |b
3     |30   |c
```

dataframe 2 (prod2)

```
id_sk | uuid|name
2     |20   |b-upd
3     |30-up|c
4     |40   |d
```

so I need the result dataframe in the below format.

```
id|col_name|values
2 |name    |b,b-upd
3 |uuid    |30,30-up
```

I did a inner join and compared the unmatched records.

I am getting the result as follows :

```
id_sk | uuid_prod1|uid_prod2|name_prod1|name_prod2
2     |20         |20       |b         |b-upd
3     |30         |30-up    |c         |c
```

```
val commmon_rec = prod1.join(prod2,prod1("id_sk")===prod2("id_sk"),"inner").select(prod1("id_sk").alias("id_sk_prod1"),prod1("uuid").alias("uuid_prod1"),prod1("name").alias("name_prod1"),prod1("name").alias("name_prod2")

val compare = spark.sql("select ...from common_rec where col_prod1<>col_prod2")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two Spark dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553300/compare-two-spark-dataframes)

Comment: Would a DatasetComparison module from https://github.com/AbsaOSS/hermes help?

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

```
//to create a joined DF with column "col_name" 
//if columns "name" and "uuid" contains different values: 
var output = df1.join(df2, df1.col("id_sk")===df2.col("id_sk"))
                .where(df1.col("name")=!=df2.col("name") || df1.col("uuid")=!=df2.col("uuid"))
                .withColumn("col_name", when(df1.col("name")=!=df2.col("name"), "name")
                                       .otherwise(when(df1.col("uuid")=!=df2.col("uuid"), "uuid")))

//to create the new "col_values" column 
//containing concatenated values:
output = output.withColumn("col_values", when(output.col("col_name")==="name", when(df1.col("name")=!=df2.col("name"), concat_ws(",", df1.col("name"), df2.col("name")) ))
                                        .when(output.col("col_name")==="uuid", when(df1.col("uuid")=!=df2.col("uuid"), concat_ws(",", df1.col("uuid"), df2.col("uuid")) )))

output = output.select(df1.col("id_sk"), output.col("col_name"), output.col("col_values"))
+-----+--------+----------+
|id_sk|col_name|col_values|
+-----+--------+----------+
|    2|    name|    b,b-up|
|    3|    uuid|  30,30-up|
+-----+--------+----------+
```

Note that I don't think this is the best possible solution, but just a starting point (for example what if one row have more than one different column values?).