# How to efficiently identify records that are different for a specific column

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dataset

I have two datasets `df1` and `df2` where I need to detect any record that is different in `df2` compare to `df1` and create a resulting dataset with an additional column that flags the records that are different. Here is an example.

```
package playground

import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, sum}

object sample4 {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Sample app")
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate()

  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  final case class Owner(a: Long,
                         b: String,
                         c: Long,
                         d: Short,
                         e: String,
                         f: String,
                         o_qtty: Double)

  final case class Result(a: Long,
                          b: String,
                          c: Long,
                          d: Short,
                          e: String,
                          f: String,
                          o_qtty: Double,
                          isDiff: Boolean)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)

    import spark.implicits._

    val data1 = Seq(
      Owner(11, "A", 666, 2017, "x", "y", 50),
      Owner(11, "A", 222, 2018, "x", "y", 20),
      Owner(33, "C", 444, 2018, "x", "y", 20),
      Owner(33, "C", 555, 2018, "x", "y", 120),
      Owner(22, "B", 555, 2018, "x", "y", 20),
      Owner(99, "D", 888, 2018, "x", "y", 100),
      Owner(11, "A", 888, 2018, "x", "y", 100),
      Owner(11, "A", 666, 2018, "x", "y", 80),
      Owner(33, "C", 666, 2018, "x", "y", 80),
      Owner(11, "A", 444, 2018, "x", "y", 50),
    )

    val data2 = Seq(
      Owner(11, "A", 666, 2017, "x", "y", 50),
      Owner(11, "A", 222, 2018, "x", "y", 20),
      Owner(33, "C", 444, 2018, "x", "y", 20),
      Owner(33, "C", 555, 2018, "x", "y", 55),
      Owner(22, "B", 555, 2018, "x", "y", 20),
      Owner(99, "D", 888, 2018, "x", "y", 100),
      Owner(11, "A", 888, 2018, "x", "y", 100),
      Owner(11, "A", 666, 2018, "x", "y", 80),
      Owner(33, "C", 666, 2018, "x", "y", 80),
      Owner(11, "A", 444, 2018, "x", "y", 50),
    )

    val expected = Seq(
      Result(11, "A", 666, 2017, "x", "y", 50, isDiff = false),
      Result(11, "A", 222, 2018, "x", "y", 20, isDiff = false),
      Result(33, "C", 444, 2018, "x", "y", 20, isDiff = false),
      Result(33, "C", 555, 2018, "x", "y", 55, isDiff = true),
      Result(22, "B", 555, 2018, "x", "y", 20, isDiff = false),
      Result(99, "D", 888, 2018, "x", "y", 100, isDiff = false),
      Result(11, "A", 888, 2018, "x", "y", 100, isDiff = false),
      Result(11, "A", 666, 2018, "x", "y", 80, isDiff = false),
      Result(33, "C", 666, 2018, "x", "y", 80, isDiff = false),
      Result(11, "A", 444, 2018, "x", "y", 50, isDiff = false),
    )


    val df1 = spark
      .createDataset(data1)
      .as[Owner]
      .cache()

    val df2 = spark
      .createDataset(data2)
      .as[Owner]
      .cache()
  }

}
```

What is the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two Spark dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553300/compare-two-spark-dataframes)

Comment: Not really, this question doesn't consider the flag to isolate the record being different.

Comment: I think the 2 answers down are not efficient, because `join` and `intersect` create hash table for all records and all partitions and compare its all. At least you can try the simplest solution: `df1.rdd.zip(df2.rdd).map {case (x,y) => (x, x != y)}` and compare speed on real dataset.
PS: it is good idea to replace one-char string to char, because char comparison is very fast

Comment: @MikhailIonkin can you provide a full answer so I can accept your answer. You are making a good point here!

Comment: done it. I have not real dataset, so I can not prove that my answer is faster, but I think it is according to test on small dataset and according to documentation

Answer (score 1):

I think this code could help you to find your answer:

```
val intersectDF=df1.intersect(df2)
val unionDF=df1.union(df2).dropDuplicates()
val diffDF= unionDF.except(intersectDF)

val intersectDF2=intersectDF.withColumn("isDiff",functions.lit(false))
val diffDF2=diffDF.withColumn("isDiff",functions.lit(true))
val answer=intersectDF2.union(diffDF2)

//Common data between two DataFrame
intersectDF2.show()
//Difference data between two DataFrame
diffDF2.show()
//Your answer
answer.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is helpful -

### Do a left join and identify un-matched columns as false

```scala
 val df1_hash = df1.withColumn("x", lit(0))
    df2.join(df1_hash, df2.columns, "left")
      .select(when(col("x").isNull, false).otherwise(true).as("isDiff") +: df2.columns.map(df2(_)): _*)
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +------+---+---+---+----+---+---+------+
      * |isDiff|a  |b  |c  |d   |e  |f  |o_qtty|
      * +------+---+---+---+----+---+---+------+
      * |true  |11 |A  |666|2017|x  |y  |50.0  |
      * |true  |11 |A  |222|2018|x  |y  |20.0  |
      * |true  |33 |C  |444|2018|x  |y  |20.0  |
      * |false |33 |C  |555|2018|x  |y  |55.0  |
      * |true  |22 |B  |555|2018|x  |y  |20.0  |
      * |true  |99 |D  |888|2018|x  |y  |100.0 |
      * |true  |11 |A  |888|2018|x  |y  |100.0 |
      * |true  |11 |A  |666|2018|x  |y  |80.0  |
      * |true  |33 |C  |666|2018|x  |y  |80.0  |
      * |true  |11 |A  |444|2018|x  |y  |50.0  |
      * +------+---+---+---+----+---+---+------+
      */
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the 2 other answers are not efficient, because `join` and `intersect` create hash table for all records and all partitions and compare its all. At least you can try the simplest solution:

```scala
  df1.rdd.zip(df2.rdd).map {
    case (x,y) => (x, x != y)
  }
```

and compare speed on real dataset.

Also it is good idea to replace one-char string to char, because char comparison is very fast.

I have not real dataset, so I can not prove that my answer is faster, but I think it is according to test on small dataset and according to documentation and reasization of `join` and `intersect`. `zip` does not exchange of partitions versus `join` or `intersect`. Sorry for my English