# Analytic in Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

In this problem we have two manager M1 and M2 , In team of manager M1 have two employee e1 & e2 and in team of M2 have two employee e4 & e5 Following is the Manager and Employee Hierarchy,

```
1)  M1
  a.    e1
  b.    e2

2)  M2
  a.    e4
  b.    e5
```

And we have following employee, salary dataframe

```
+------+--------+------+---------+
|emp_id|month_id|salary|work_days|
+------+--------+------+---------+
|e1    |1       |66000 |22       |
|e1    |2       |48000 |16       |
|e1    |3       |87000 |29       |
|e2    |1       |75000 |25       |
|e2    |4       |69000 |23       |
|e2    |5       |66000 |22       |
|e4    |1       |90000 |30       |
|e4    |2       |87000 |29       |
|e5    |3       |72000 |24       |
|e5    |1       |57000 |19       |
|e5    |4       |51000 |17       |
|e5    |5       |69000 |23       |
+------+--------+------+---------+
```

Find new dataframe with following rules

Rule 1- Manager can see work_days of his team

Rule 2 – Employee can see his work_days and salary

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: so what is that you have tried and not working?

Comment: Hi, @Juan find work_days of team of each manager using above Dataframe

Comment: @Ram,give me some hint to proceed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I understood from your question, here's what I suggest you to do.

First you need to create dataframes of managers with employees under them as

manager1

```
+---+------+
|sn |emp_id|
+---+------+
|a  |e1    |
|b  |e2    |
+---+------+
```

manager2

```
+---+------+
|sn |emp_id|
+---+------+
|a  |e4    |
|b  |e5    |
+---+------+
```

Then you should write a function that will return a list of employees under a manager as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def getEmployees(df : DataFrame): List[String] = {
  df.select(collect_list("emp_id")).first().getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[String]](0).toList
}
```

The final step is to write a function that will filter only the employees passed as

```
def getEmployeeDetails(df: DataFrame, list: List[String]) : DataFrame ={
  df.filter(df("emp_id").isin(list: _*))
}
```

now if you want to see employees under manager1(m1) then

```
getEmployeeDetails(df, getEmployees(m1)).show(false)
```

will return you

```
+------+--------+------+---------+
|emp_id|month_id|salary|work_days|
+------+--------+------+---------+
|e1    |1       |66000 |22       |
|e1    |2       |48000 |16       |
|e1    |3       |87000 |29       |
|e2    |1       |75000 |25       |
|e2    |4       |69000 |23       |
|e2    |5       |66000 |22       |
+------+--------+------+---------+
```

you can do the same for other managers too

you can do the same for employees too as

```
getEmployeeDetails(df, List("e1")).show(false)
```

will return the dataframe of employee1 (e1)

```
+------+--------+------+---------+
|emp_id|month_id|salary|work_days|
+------+--------+------+---------+
|e1    |1       |66000 |22       |
|e1    |2       |48000 |16       |
|e1    |3       |87000 |29       |
+------+--------+------+---------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful